# Why isn't this Math.random method working?

Tags: math, random, return

Since Java doesn't allow to return two types in one method, I thought best way to do it is to use get methods.

Simply, I wanted computer to generate two random numbers, and if they were not the same I wanted it to print sum of them. If they were the same, I wanted it to roll once more and sum all of the rolls. Until here, it was okay, but then I wanted to see not only sum, but also the numbers that computer generated randomly before adding them up. Therefore, it had to be several return types.

But it prints 0 three times instead.

Can you help me with this? I want to learn what is wrong exactly with this code and if it can be done neater and cleaner? I know Java loves long ways..

Thank you.

```
class App {

    public static int monopolyRoll(int side) {

        double randomNumber = Math.random();

        randomNumber = randomNumber * side;

        randomNumber = randomNumber + 1;

        int randomInt = (int) randomNumber;

        return randomInt;

    }

    private int roll1 = monopolyRoll(6);
    private int roll2 = monopolyRoll(6);

    public int userRolls() {

        if (roll1 != roll2) {

            return roll1 + roll2;

        } else {

            int roll3 = monopolyRoll(6);
            int roll4 = monopolyRoll(6);

            return roll1 + roll2 + roll3 + roll4;
        }
    }

    private static int first;
    private static int second;
    private static int third;

    public App(int first, int second, int third) {
        App.first = roll1;
        App.second = roll2;
        App.third = userRolls();
    }

    public static int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public static int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public static int getThird() {
        return third;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int first = getFirst();
        int second = getSecond();
        int third = getThird();

        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);
        System.out.println(third);

    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't really described what the problem is.  In what way is this code not working as expected?  When you step through in a debugger, where specifically does the problem happen?

Comment: Why does the constructor `App(...)` have arguments if they are never used and do also have no apparent purpose? -- Do you ever only execute one dice roll or do you expect to use this functionality repeatedly?

Comment: I updated it thanks for reminding. It just prints 0 three times.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` works, but you never actually *call* it in your application.  This is what your application does:

```
int first = getFirst();
int second = getSecond();
int third = getThird();

System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(second);
System.out.println(third);
```

That's it.  Aside from the single `return` statements in those getter methods and the declared-but-never-assigned integers they return (so, zeroes), none of that other code ever executes.

I suspect this is coming from a bit of a misunderstanding on your part about the `static` keyword.  By sprinkling around the `static` keyword until the code compiled, what you've done is create something that's syntactically correct but doesn't do anything :)

As a bit of a learning exercise, try moving all of the business logic out of the `App` class, leaving only the `main()` method as the application's entry point.  And removing all `static` keywords from the new class you create.  This should make the use of that class more clear.

Something like:

```
class Roller {
    private int roll1;
    private int roll2;
    // other private variables

    private int monopolyRoll(int side) {
        // your code
    }

    // your other methods, also private and non-static

    public Roller(int first, int second, int third) {
        this.first = roll1;
        this.second = roll2;
        this.third = userRolls();
    }

    // and so on
}
```

The idea here is to make things *instance-based* (non-static) by default.  Also make things `private` by default until explicitly needed to be accessed outside the class.  Currently the only things your class needs to expose publicly are the constructor and the getters.

Then in the `main()` method you'll need to create an instance of your class to use it.  Something like this:

```
Roller roller = new Roller(1, 2, 3);

int first = roller.getFirst();
int second = roller.getSecond();
int third = roller.getThird();

System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(second);
System.out.println(third);
```

Comment: Okay, it perfectly works thank you, but is there any way to make it work with less lines?